# Displaying 0/1 as no/yes from MYSQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with a row that is either going to be a 0 or a 1. However, I want to be able to display the table with PHP and have 0 show up as no, and 1 show up as yes. I am still a beginner with PHP and have been searching for a way to do it, but have had no luck. The row in question is the 'masterwork' row. The line of code I thought would do it is

`$row['masterwork'] = ( intval( $row['masterwork']) == 1) ? "YES" : "NO";`

Here is the code that displays the table:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM weapons");

$row['masterwork'] = ( intval( $row['masterwork']) == 1) ? "YES" : "NO";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<center>";
  echo "<table border='1' class='display'>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Weapon Name: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weaponName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Creator: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['creator'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Weapon Category: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weaponCategory'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Weapon Sub-Category: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weaponSubCategory'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Cost: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['costAmount'] . " " . $row['costType'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Damage(S): </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['damageS'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Damage(M): </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['damageM'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Critical: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['critical'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Range Increment: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['rangeIncrement'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Weight: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weight'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Weapon Type: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weaponType'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Masterwork: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['masterwork'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Special Abilities: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['specialAbilities'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Additional Info: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['additionalInfo'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
echo "</center>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Your `$row['masterwork'] = ( intval( $row['masterwork']) == 1) ? "YES" : "NO";` line should probably be *inside* the `while` loop.

Comment: Way too overcomplicated. `echo $row['field'] ? 'Yes' : 'No';`

Comment: @RocketHazmat wow that was it...... I just added '$row['masterwork'] = ( intval( $row['masterwork']) == 1) ? "YES" : "NO";' into the while loop and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this --

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM weapons");



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $row['masterwork'] = ( intval( $row['masterwork']) == 1) ? "YES" : "NO";
  echo "<center>";
  echo "<table border='1' class='display'>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Weapon Name: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weaponName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Creator: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['creator'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Weapon Category: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weaponCategory'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Weapon Sub-Category: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weaponSubCategory'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Cost: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['costAmount'] . " " . $row['costType'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Damage(S): </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['damageS'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Damage(M): </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['damageM'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Critical: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['critical'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Range Increment: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['rangeIncrement'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Weight: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weight'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Weapon Type: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weaponType'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Masterwork: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['masterwork'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Special Abilities: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['specialAbilities'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Additional Info: </td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['additionalInfo'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
echo "</center>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i changed it to after reading @RocketHazmat's post. It works now.